# How to save and provide an external JWT token in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, token, kubernetes-pod

## **Hi world !**

## My problem :

I have one kubernetes cluster with many pods that run the same symfony app. On this app, I make a request on HERE's api for geocoding. HERE sends me a JWT token available for 24h. I would like to save this token in kubernetes, in this way, all pods/app have the same token.

## My question is :

Is there a good practice, approved solution, to get a jwt token on external API and save it in kubernetes for provide it to my pods ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [kubernetes secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) for storing the token. Mount the secret in the pod for using it to call external API.

Here is the [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/) on distributing credentials securely using secrets.

As a side note kubernetes itself uses secret to store service account credential which is a JWT token. So this approach is approved and mainstream.